# Laravel 5.6 - GroupBy is not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, laravel-5.6

I have tried it in several ways but it doesn't work (seems like ignoring it). So what I tried:

```
$user->notes()->groupBy('title')->get();
```

Above way completely ignores groupBy and just returns collection of notes.

```
Note::where('user_id', $user->id)->groupBy('title')->get();
```

Exactly same output with this one too.

---

In my `database.php`, the database is set to `'strict' => false`

---

I have also tried using raw db query, it returns it in a weird format (returns 1 row for each title when I use groupBy)

```
DB::table('notes')->where('user_id', $user->id)->groupBy('title')->get();
```

---

I have seen many people facing this issue however none of the suggested ways  (above) solved the issue.

I can achieve what I want with using `collection->each(function ($note) {...} )`, however while there is groupBy to make achieve this easily with 1 line, why the heavy work..

Does anyone has any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: I suggest you to [debug the query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries) (search for "Listening For Query Events").

Comment: I'll do that next time I face this issue. Currently overcame it with `collection->each()`. Will update here

Comment: If you are using Blade, you can see the queries for a given route using [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).

Comment: Could you please show the schema for the notes table? And what is your database driver and version?

Comment: Can you show result `dd(Note::where('user_id', $user->id)->groupBy('title')->toSql());`

Comment: Try with SELECT statement it should be like this :
DB::table('notes')->select('title','Other_field')->where('user_id', $user->id)->groupBy('title')->get()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you just need to call first the ->get() then the ->groupBy() method.
Thats because in a SQL Query you need to select first the elements, then group.

So your code need to be like:

```
DB::table('notes')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get()->groupBy('title');
```

Heres an example of a Group By Query:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
ORDER BY column_name(s);
```

Comment: I'm not so sure about this. The `get()` method runs the query so I think it needs to be called last. That's how you find it in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset).

Comment: I have tried a minutes ago and worked (with laravel 5.3)

Comment: I think you might be calling the [Collection's groupBy() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby).

Comment: I should confirm that I made it work with Collection's `groupBy()` method but not the query builder one

Answer (score 0):

go with select() and please add your group by field  in select

```
   e.g DB::table('notes')->select('title','Other_field')->where('user_id', $user->id)->groupBy('title')->get();
```